# SQL Server - Find Sites that have employees but no admin

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

Trying to put together a sql query and currently a little stuck as I'm fairly new. I need to put together a query which will return all sites within the database where staff are employed - But do not have anyone set as the SA (`UR.RoleID = 13`)

What i've got so far:

```
Select 
    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
From 
    Sites S 
Left Join 
    Users U ON S.SiteID = U.SiteID 
Inner Join 
    UsersRoles UR ON U.UserID = UR.UserID
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

A couple of `exists` operators should do the trick:

```
SELECT SiteID, SiteName
FROM   Sites s
WHERE  
       -- Site has users assigned to it
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   Users u
               WHERE  u.SiteId = U.SiteId)
       -- Site doesn't have an admin
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   Users u
                       JOIN   UserRoles ur ON ur.UserId = u.UserId
                       WHERE  u.SiteId = U.SiteId AND ur.RoleId = 13)
```